# Can't activate the Terminal Server in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, licensing

I receive the following error message when I try to register my Terminal Server in Windows Server 2003. The server is online and able to access the internet.

The License Server Activation Wizard encountered an internal error from the license server.

Message Number: 0xc0110011

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2021885

Comment: After registering every time I open Terminal Server Licensing. I receive the following error "No Terminal Server license server is available in the current domain or workgroup. To connect to another license server, click Action and click Connect and then type the server name. Once I type it the server it locates it. Should this be something I'm concerned with? 

Thanks

Comment: 1) Try to specify a license server manually: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279561/

2) Terminal Server keeps a list of license servers (if found) in registry. Enterprise licensing servers are stored in the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSLicensing\Parameters \EnterpriseServerMulti, and domain licensing servers are stored in the HKLM\Software\Microsoft\MSLicensing\Parameters\DomainLicenseServerMulti. Once a license server is found, the Terminal Server will only start the discovery process over again if it can’t connect to any of the servers in the registry.